# Curl не отправляет POST-запрос с JSON

Tags: php, curl

При отправке запроса с помощью `Curl`, используя данный код, при выводе `$_POST` получаю пустой массив , если убрать `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));`, то приходит, криво, но что-то приходит, так вот, как правильно настроить `Curl` для корректной отправки `JSON`

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);    
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataPost);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json')); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);        
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            $headerSent = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT ); 
            curl_close($ch); 
            return $result;
```

в `$dataPost`

```
{
                     "ID": 999999999 ,
                      "Territory": [ "1", "2" ],
                      "Country": [ "1", "2" ],
                      "BeginDate": "2018-31-05",
                      "EndDate": "2019-31-05",
                      "TripTerm": 90,
                      "Currency": 978,
                      "Option": 1,
                      "Age": [
                            {
                              "Category": 1,
                              "Count": 1
                            },
                            {
                              "Category": 2,
                              "Count": 1
                            },
                            {
                              "Category": 3,
                              "Count": 1
                            },
                            {
                              "Category": 4,
                              "Count": 0
                            },
                            {
                              "Category": 5,
                              "Count": 0
                            },
                            {
                              "Category": 6,
                              "Count": 0
                            },
                            {
                              "Category": 7,
                              "Count": 0
                            }
                        ]
                      ,

                      "Summ": 10000
                    }
```

Comment: а что у вас в `$dataPost`?

Comment: И замените `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));` на `сurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));`

Comment: @InDevX в `$dataPost` добавил в шапке , строка `сurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));` не помогла

Comment: @InDevX на выходе массив выходит исковерканный

Comment: С заголовком это мой косяк, не верно понял, он верный у вас стоит

Comment: `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` зачем дублируются?

Comment: Попробуйте в заголовки ещё отправить content-length. как-то так: `array( 'Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($dataPost) )`

Comment: @InDevX когда стоит заголовок `array('Content-Type:application/json')` , при выводе получается пустой массив. вывожу `print_r($_POST)` ,может я не так вывожу , и поправьте

Comment: @InDevX при добавлении  `array( 'Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($dataPost) )` тоже самое, пустой массив

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` и должен быть пустой, т.к. он заполняется только если идет запрос с параметризованным телом, например если CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS это ассоциативный массив.

В вашем случае тело запроса есть строка `json` поэтому на сервере получить ее можно через

```
file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Comment: а если сервер написан на шарпе и не совсем понятно как реализован прием данных , что в таком случае можно сделать

Comment: на шарпе не знаю как получить)) но это стандартные механизмы, думаю если загуглить решение найдется сразу

Comment: поэтому и я тут , так как найти не могу

Comment: "Поэтому я тут, ищу, как в РНР заполнить массив $__POST". Л - Логика!